# Is there anyway to remove all related information of an object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just wonder how can I remove all related information of a student that I want to change in python. Thank you

this is my app.py

```py
        # change student information    
        if choice == 2:
            student_name = input("Please enter a student name that you want to change information:")
            with open("student.txt", "r") as file:
                lines = file.readlines()
            update_line = []
            found_student = False
            
            for line in lines:
                if line.startswith("Name: " + student_name):
                    student = Student(input("Please enter the updated student name: "), input("Please enter the updated student major: "), input("Please enter the updated student GPA: "))
                    update_line.append("Name: " + str(student.name) + "\n")
                    update_line.append("Major: " + str(student.major) + "\n")
                    update_line.append("GPA: " + str(student.gpa) + "\n")
                    update_line.append("On Probation: " + str(student.on_probation()) + "\n\n")
                    found_student = True
                else:
                    update_line.append(line)
                   
            if found_student:
                with open("student.txt", "w") as file:
                    file.writelines(update_line)
                    print("Successfully updated")
                    file.close()
            else:
                print("Failed to update or student not found.") `                            
            
user_options()
```

output

```
Name: John
Major: IT
GPA: 1.9
On Probation: True

Name: Bunnie
Major: Hos
GPA: 3.6
On Probation: False

#I want to remove these as it was the old student information
Major: Art
GPA: 3.0
On Probation: False

Name: Johh Park
Major: Business
GPA: 2.0
On Probation: False

Name: Van Hien
Major: Art
GPA: 3.1
On Probation: False
```

I tried to use loop to remove all the remain line of that object but it just removed all the lines

Comment: What do you mean "remove"? And what information?

Comment: This really needs some more modularization as I expect there's rampant duplication in your code. For example, why can't you implement `__str__` for your `Student` that can do the output, so then you can just `update_line.append(str(student))` and be done with it.

Comment: This is also the case where a simple database like SQLite would be way better than a flat-file that can easily get corrupted.

Comment: I want to change the information of a student. I input all new data, but it just remove the name of old student and push all remain info down

Comment: got it, let me try

Comment: This is where something like [SQLAlchemy with SQLite](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/sqlite.html) really shines. It's serverless, and you can update specific fields without having to concern yourself with how that data is updated on disk. You can focus instead on your application logic. Admittedly learning SQL can be a bit of a hurdle, but there's a ton of material out there on it, and it is a very powerful tool once understood.

Comment: just checked it out, I'm gonna test it

Comment: You need to read *all* the lines of the file for a student before you process it. The way you're doing it, when you replace the `Name:` line you leave all the other lines for that student.

Comment: Or after you write the new information for the student, read all the lines until the next blank line before you return to the beginning of the loop.

Comment: @Barmar I want to let user can change GPA and major as well so that's why

Comment: @Barmar can you please write the example for me as I'm not confident with read and write in python?, still learning it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `readlines()` to read the entire file into a list, loop over the file directly with `for line in file:`. Then you can have an inner loop that reads lines until the next blank line, so you skip over the remaining lines for a student when you modify them.

```
        if choice == 2:
            student_name = input("Please enter a student name that you want to change information:")
            found_student = False
            update_line = []

            with open("student.txt", "r") as file:
                for line in file:
                    if line == "Name: " + student_name:
                        student = Student(input("Please enter the updated student name: "), input("Please enter the updated student major: "), input("Please enter the updated student GPA: "))
                        update_line.append("Name: " + str(student.name) + "\n")
                        update_line.append("Major: " + str(student.major) + "\n")
                        update_line.append("GPA: " + str(student.gpa) + "\n")
                        update_line.append("On Probation: " + str(student.on_probation()) + "\n\n")
                        found_student = True
                        # skip until the next blank line
                        for line in file:
                            if line == '\n':
                                break
                    else:
                        update_line.append(line)

            if found_student:
                with open("student.txt", "w") as file:
                    file.writelines(update_line)
                    print("Successfully updated")
            else:
                print("Failed to update or student not found.")
```

As mentioned in the comments, a database like SQLite would make things easier. Or instead of using multiple lines for each student, you could use a CSV file. Or use JSON or Pickle to write a whole list or dictionary to the file.

In general, you should decide whether the file is intended for humans or computers. The same format is not always best for both.